# Django] Saving multiple images by formset doesn't work

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to save multiple Images and his parent's data together on the same template.

I have one parent's model(to save normal data) and child's model(to save images). In this case, saving parent's data is working very well. but images are not work.
There isn't any error message.

//model

```
class QuotationPanchok(models.Model):
    whose = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='', default='')
    many = models.IntegerField(default='1', help_text='')
    design = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=(('yes', 'yes'), ('no', 'no'),))
    sian = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=(('yes','yes'), ('no', 'no'),))
    havefile = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=(('yes','yes'), ('no', 'no'),))
    deadline = models.DateField(blank=True)
    addressto = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', help_text='')
    fulltext = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=(('not','not'), ('finish', 'finish'),), default='not')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class ImagesForQuotation(models.Model):
    whose = models.ForeignKey(QuotationPanchok, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.whose.title + " Image"
```

// views

```
def quotation_create(request):
    ImageFormset = modelformset_factory(ImagesForQuotation, fields=('image',), extra=4)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuotationCreateForm(request.POST)
        formset = ImageFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.whose = request.user
            post.save()

            for f in formset:
                try:
                    photo = ImagesForQuotation(whose=post, image=f.cleaned_date['image'])
                    photo.save()
                except Exception as e:
                    break
            return redirect('index')

    else:
        form = QuotationCreateForm()
        formset = ImageFormset(queryset=ImagesForQuotation.objects.none())

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'quotationapp/quotation_create.html', context)
```

//forms

```
class QuotationCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = QuotationPanchok
        fields = (
            'title',
            'many',
            'design',
            'sian',
            'havefile',
            'deadline',
            'addressto',
            'fulltext',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuotationCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

//template(quotation_create.html)

```
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{ formset.as_table }}

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you..